# Will POItracker work when the app is in the background - Skobbler

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

If a user starts a route with several POIs added to his route, and POI tracker set up, is it possible to send some notifications to a user, when he is 2 miles from that POI, if the app is in the Background?
Will delegate methods even be called, when the app is not in the foreground?

It's a new feature we would like to implement, and it's in the planning process right now, so wanted to check if this functionality is possible, before we continue with planning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - this feature should also work while the app is navigating in the background (navigation, either on route or free drive, is a prerequisite for POI tracking to work).